# jQuery show/hide slideToggle not working

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I tried to integrate this [FAQ template](http://codyhouse.co/gem/css-faq-template/) to Magento store's "1 column layout".

Show/hide Toggle is not working as expected, it hides back as soon as duration(400) is over.
You can check it live at: http://nutrija.com/faq

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

var faqTrigger = $('.cd-faq-trigger'),

    //show faq content clicking on faqTrigger
    faqTrigger.on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).next('.cd-faq-content').slideToggle(400).end().parent('li').toggleClass('content-visible');
    });

}
```

I tried changing few parameters but failed, kindly help.

Comment: There are 2 syntax errors in your posted code. Is that your current code?

Comment: Full main.js file is here: http://codepad.org/vDQAxte5

Comment: Static html works well outside Magento. http://nutrija.com/static-faq.html

Answer (score 0):

Do the `content-visible` class toggle in slideToggle Callback

```
var faqTrigger = $('.cd-faq-trigger'),

//show faq content clicking on faqTrigger
faqTrigger.on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).next('.cd-faq-content').slideToggle(400, function(){
               //Add toggle class here
               faqTrigger.parent('li').toggleClass('content-visible');
         });
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue, the problem was in integrating jQuery with Magento

**Solution:**

when using jQuery you must ensure it is using 'noConflict' mode. To do this, add:

var $j=jQuery.noConflict();

to the end of your jQuery script.

and now, alter any jQuery code as follows. If you have:

```
//show faq content clicking on faqTrigger
faqTrigger.on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).next('.cd-faq-content').slideToggle(400).end().parent('li').toggleClass('content-visible');
});
```

}

alter it to:

```
//show faq content clicking on faqTrigger
faqTrigger.on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $f(this).next('.cd-faq-content').slideToggle(400).end().parent('li').toggleClass('content-visible');
});
```

}